# Analytics Embed API - rounding BounceRate in table

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, rounding, google-analytics-api

Hello I've been working with Analytics Embed API and get most of the stuff done, but my BounceRate in table is weird: instead of rounding it off, my code is making lot of numbers after dot.

Here's da code:

```js
 var womwykresliczba = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
                query: {
                    'ids': 'ga:47537437',    // THIS NEEDS TO BE A VIEW
                    //'start-date': '30daysAgo',  // THAT YOUR SERVICE ACCOUNT HAS
                    //'end-date': 'yesterday',   // ACCESS TO
                    'metrics': 'ga:bounceRate'
                },
                chart: {
                    'container': 'wo-mwykres-liczba',
                    'type': 'TABLE',
                    'options': {
                        'title': 'Współczynnik odrzuceń'
                    }
                }
            });
```

Hope some of you can help.
Thanks in advance.